# Revision history formatting bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown, revisions-list

So this is the second super-obscure layout "bug" I've found. When one looks at the revision history of a question on SO, the headers normally look like this:

[image: Normal header]

However, if the edit description goes onto a second line, the "view source" link is pushed down a bit too much - it doesn't look like the header expands enough (it's ever-so-slightly bigger) or adds a buffer to account for the extra line:

[image: Buggy header for two-line comment]

[image: Three line comment]

This is all monumentally unimportant in the grand scheme of things, but I figured I might as well mention it.

(This was viewed with Firefox 4 on Windows.)

([The original link can be found here for your viewing pleasure.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5804803/revisions))

Comment: Thanks @Arjan! Good edit. Now if only we could upvote edits...

Comment: Ha! Firefox 4?!? 2011 called: they want.. oh wait, never mind. This was from 2011.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's "Better Late Than Never" week!

This will be fixed in the next build - rev 2014.4.23.2184 here on MSE and rev 2014.4.23.1564 elsewhere.